# PyQGIS raster calculator code not working

Tags: raster, pyqgis, raster-calculator

I'm trying to write the raster calculator as part of a Python script for use with my other code.
The below code runs with no errors but no output file is put in the directory.

Can anyone advise me what the issue is that this function doesn't appear to be working?

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from qgis.analysis import  *
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

layer_a = QgsRasterLayer('C:/Users/Public/try/singlebeam.tif','singlebeam') 
entries_a = [] 
band = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry() 
band.ref = layer_a.name() + '@1' 
band.raster = layer_a 
band.bandNumber = 1 
entries_a.append(band)

layer_b = QgsRasterLayer('C:/Users/Public/try/multibeam.tif', 'multibeam') 
entries_b = [] 
band = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry() 
band.ref = layer_b.name() + '@1' 
band.raster = layer_b 
band.bandNumber = 1 
entries_b.append(band)

expression = '("singlebeam@1" = 0) * "multibeam@1" + ("singlebeam@1" != 0) * "singlebeam@1"'

path_to_output_file = 'C:/Users/Public/try/pycalc.tif'
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression,
                           path_to_output_file,
                           'GTiff',
                           layer_a.extent(),
                           layer_a.width(),
                           layer_a.height(),
                           entries_a) 
result = calc.processCalculation()


print("Complete!")
```

Comment: We can not guess what "appears" to not be working, please be specific in what you expect, why you expect it and what actually happens.

Comment: I expect the expression to be applied to the 2 input rasters that I have specified and the output saved to the specified directory. However this isn't the case but the code is running with no errors

Comment: Instead of printing `"Complete!"`, you should print `result` to get a meaningful return value from the `processCalculation()` method. You can check the integer value returned against the enumerator values here: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterCalculator.html#abd4932102407a12b53036588893fa2cc  to see what type of error you are getting. 0 being success and 1-7 for errors.

Comment: Is the expression not applied or is the output not saved? What do you get in the output file? Please be really specific.